# Manually update access_token for google oauth2 in python

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-python-api

I'm using google oauthlib to get an `access_token` and use it to get gmail atom feed using `requests` because it is not supported by the python lib.

When using supported services such as drive, the token is automatically refreshed, how to do that in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have your refresh token you can use it to request a new Access token using HTTP POST

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=1/ffYmfI0sjR54Ft9oupubLzrJhD1hZS5tWQcyAvNECCA&grant_type=refresh_token

this Link may help [Google 3 legged oauth2 flow](https://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/)